# I am losing session data when being redirected from Payment GateWay

Tags: java, jsp, session, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC for handling requests and responses.
I'm putting data related to a selected product and customer details in session and making the user navigate to the payment gateway.

When the payment was successful, the user is redirected back to my site. At that point, the session data is lost.

Please help me in this problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: what you are storing in session?

Comment: language corrections to body and title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payment gateway could be on a different domain (www.paymentgateway.com) from you site (www.site.com). Since the session is normally bound per domain/per context path, you could be losing your session when changing the domain.